# Puppet Roles/Profiles with Overlapping Profiles

Tags: linux, design-patterns, puppet

I am attempting to implement Puppet with the roles & profiles pattern. I have identified two distinct profiles at this point:

- `security` profile: provides a wide range of security-related configurations to hosts.
- `ad_client` profile: provides configurations to enable AD authentication to Linux clients.

I think these both make sense as independent profiles because either one may apply to a given host not necessarily both. Therefore, I think I have to make each one complete (i.e. fully instantiate classes in each) so that it can stand on its own.

However, for hosts that may require both of these profiles there exists fairly substantial overlap (e.g. both configure `pam`, `sshd` and `sssd`).

How can one create modular profiles but avoid such overlap?

Comment: Can we assume that in fact every node will get the security profile whereas only specific nodes will get the ad_client profile?

Comment: That's probably a fair assumption 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that the security profile is in fact needed everywhere, then you should try to split up your classes along the following lines:

```
# common to all nodes.
class profile::base {
  include profile::base::ssh
  include profile::base::pam
  include profile::base::sssd
  include profile::base::security
  ...
}

# for nodes that also need the ad_client
class profile::ad_client {
  include profile::base
  ...
}
```

Let me know if there is some edge-case that you have not specified that prevents you doing it this way, and I will expand.

Comment: What is the benefit of creating a profile wrapping individual component modules like ssh and pam? Why not just include those component modules in the 'base' profile?

Comment: I guess what I was envisioning was the ability to have my Hiera configurations be self-documenting. That is that I could provide the specific configurations for 'profile::security' and 'profile::ad_client' so that it was obvious which required parameters belonged to each profile.

Comment: Typically `base` is a role.

Comment: @LJKims I assumed this was a question about how to avoid duplicate declarations, rather than one about how to do Hiera. So, I imagined you are doing a minimalist SSH config where your config is so sparse that you do not need a dedicated SSH module. But of course, if you have an external ssh module, then just declare it in `profile::base`. I fully understand your desire for self-documenting code - nothing is more important - but I am afraid with the information provided I am not quite able to understand the specifics.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have only ever seen a `profile::base`, including in the official Puppet examples e.g. https://docs.puppet.com/pe/2017.2/r_n_p_full_example.html  In Craig Dunn's original post he uses class inheritance, and while I like his patterns, the Puppet community developed a rather strange fear of inheritance! So I have never seen it actually done that way.

Comment: Maybe I muddied it a bit. It's not really about Hiera but that would be a handy side effect. Many modules, like sssd, expect to be called once and configure the technology fully. However, the security module and ad_client modules have different requirements (but can be merged) for how the sssd module is instantiated. The question is how to make each module stand alone but also be able to be used together when they both declare (resource-like) the same modules.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Class inheritance has been actively discouraged by Puppet for a few years now due to its unpredictable behavior. The `params` pattern is also replaced now by Hiera 5's module data..

Comment: @LJKims If you find two modules on the Forge that each try to fully configure a dependency - like sssd - in a slightly different way, you simply can't use those two modules together. In that situation, unfortunately, you would need to write at least some of the code yourself. Without knowing the specifics I can't give you a better option.

Comment: Let me ask this generally: Is it common practice to implement common configuration for multiple profiles at a single component module level (given that most Forge modules tend to use templates for config file deployment) or is it better to rewrite a module using some defined type to make its resources available to other modules/profiles?

Comment: We are probably veering into the realm of opinion now, and there is probably no right answer. I regard it as a best practice for a Forge Module to "do one thing well", but there will be exceptions. Certainly, if you have a module that is configuring a whole bunch of things like sssd and ssh, it might be hard in practice to make that module play nice with other Forge modules, so we should try to avoid doing that. E.g. instead of module X configuring its own SSH, it would be better to call out to the ghoneycutt/ssh module. But this is programming - there are always exceptions.